# Hashing sensitive information for searching in MySQL

Tags: security, encryption, hash, php-5.3, mysql-5.1

I have fields in a MySQL table that NEED to be encrypted. Since they are encrypted I can't search on them in MySQL, I have read not to use AES_ENCRYPT in MySQL 5.1 so I would be using PHP to do the encryption/decryption.  My application would need to search on these key pieces of information to prevent duplicate records from making its way into the table.

These fields for this question would be **First Name**, **Last Name** & **Date Of Birth**

My thoughts are I would need to use some sort of hash, how would I successfully hash this information to create a unique key but keeping it secure. I assume adding a unique salt would help with security (Rainbow table) but then how would I search?

This key would strictly be used to keep unique records, it is not used for authentication.

Comment: I suggest checking out this article: http://outsourcedbits.org/2013/10/06/how-to-search-on-encrypted-data-part-1/